# What is diffrence between ChatterMention and without ChatterMention in salesforce

Tags: apex, chatter, chatter-feed

I am working on Case standard salesforce object and i want to post the feeditem on Chatter Post for cases. There is some condition like if case.recordtype!=abc then mention user on chatter post otherwise do not mention user.

I don't know what is chatter mention user? Anyone have brief idea?

Answer (score 0):

Chatter mention is nothing but use of `@mention` in chatter post.

[@Mention People and Groups in Posts and Comments](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_mention_visibility.htm&type=0)

> @Mention individual people or a group to keep them informed when you're discussing something relevant to them.

1. When you write a post, type @ followed by the first few letters of the person or group name.
2. Select the person or group from the list of matches.
   The list includes all matches for

   - People, typically users you interact with the most
   - Public groups
   - Private groups you’re a member of
     You can have up to 25 mentions in a single post or comment. You can’t mention archived groups, unlisted groups, customer groups, and private groups you’re not a member of.
3. Click Share to post your update.